# delphi, help needed "Making the computer count"

Tags: delphi

My textbook says I need to make a program/game that whenever I move my pointer over the button, the button moves to a random location on the form.
Then, I need a label displaying how many times I tried to click on the button.
Here's the code:

```
procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  iCount : Integer;
begin
 randomize;
 iCount := iCount + 1;   //my textbook explains barely anything to me!
end;


procedure TForm1.btnClickMeMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
begin
 labelOutput.caption := IntToStr (iCount);
 btnClickMe.Top := Random (Form1.ClientHeight - 5 - btnClickMe.Height);
 btnClickMe.Left := Random (Form1.ClientWidth - 5 - btnClickMe.width);
end;


end.
```

Where I say `labelOutput.caption := IntToStr (iCount);`, it gives me an error saying `Value assigned to 'iCount' never used`
I also need to know how to do this before I carry on with other exercises.
Thanks..

Comment: Does the code you have now compile? If it does what doesn't work?

Your variable iCount should be defined in the interface, under where is says private: `iCount: integer`. The way you have it now iCount now it probably isn't declared in the `btnClickMeMouseMove` method.

Comment: First, `iCount` needs to be more global. Second, it should be increased in `MouseMove`, not when the form is activated.

Comment: You need a variable that endures. Local variables only live as long as the function that declares them. You need a field of your form type to hold the counter.

Comment: Get a better textbook! And if you think about it, if the button moves away as soon as the mouse moves over it, you will never be able to click the button with the mouse (you can still click it using the keyboard, though).

Comment: Randomize should only be called once, in FormCreate for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others told you, you need declare your variable in the Form's interface (if you are not already), but more importantly you need to increment it in the button's `OnMouseMove` event, not in the form's `OnActivate` event (you should use the `OnCreate` event instead).

Try this:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    labelOutput: TLabel;
    btnClickMe: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnClickMeMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  private
    iCount : Integer;
  end;
```

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Randomize;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnClickMeMouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  iCount := iCount + 1;
  labelOutput.Caption := IntToStr (iCount);
  btnClickMe.Left := Random (ClientWidth - btnClickMe.Width);
  btnClickMe.Top := Random (ClientHeight - btnClickMe.Height);
end;
```